# How to transfer custom token

Tags: rust, solana

I want to send my deployed token other than sol using rust solana-sdk, but I don't know how. I've been looking for the official documentation for a long time, but I can't find it. Could you please let me know if you have any information on this? Thanks

Comment: The official documentation for the rust solana crate would be here: https://docs.rs/solana/0.17.2/solana/

Comment: https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/1.8.0/solana_sdk/system_transaction/fn.transfer.html This could help.

Answer (score 0):

The package with these bindings is the `spl-token` package: https://docs.rs/spl-token/3.2.0/spl_token/

You can see some examples of how to use it all over the solana-program-library code, but perhaps the spl-token CLI will be helpful: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/e8b7009cc4d8cdd87232ccfc9ce93ab203ada496/token/cli/src/main.rs#L707